# Is there a way to execute a command from within a string or have more than one body in a powershell email?

Tags: powershell, email, scripting

I'm trying to send an email that contains both some information that I type out as well as the contents of a text file that was generated in earlier code. I was wondering if there is a convenient way of doing so without sending two emails? The code below didn't work but I can get the message to send if I only have the text or only have the contents of the txt file. Thanks!

`` Send-MailMessage -SMTPServer localhost -To myemail@email.com -From myemail@email.com -Subject "TESTING Active Domain Replication Failure TESTING" -Body "The following Domain Controller has had a replication failure. Please see attached txt files for more information. `n"(Get-Content -Path .\causeOfFailure.txt | out-string) -attachment error.zip ``

So I edited the statement to look like this:

```
$fileContent = (Get-Content -Path .\causeOfFailure.txt)
compress-archive -Path causeOfFailure.txt,dnsInformation.txt -update -DestinationPath error.zip
Send-MailMessage -SMTPServer localhost -To email@email.com -From email@email.com -Subject "TESTING Active Domain Replication Failure TESTING" -Body "The following Domain Controller has had a replication failure. Please see attached txt files for more information. `n & $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($fileContent)" -attachment error.zip
```

The output in the email shows this message

> "System.Management.Automation.EngineIntrinsics.InvokeCommand.ExpandString(Source Controller:".

Is there a better way to have a string followed by a function both be part of the body of an email with the send-mailmessage command?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add the contents of a file to the body of the email, you can simply use $() to include functions within the quotes.

```
Send-MailMessage -SMTPServer localhost -To email@email.com -From email@email.com -Subject "TESTING Active Domain Replication Failure TESTING" -Body "The following Domain Controller has had a replication failure. Please see attached txt files for more information. `n $fileContent" -attachment error.zip
```

If you want to include the function within your script, you can do this,

```
Send-MailMessage -SMTPServer localhost -To email@email.com -From email@email.com -Subject "TESTING Active Domain Replication Failure TESTING" -Body "The following Domain Controller has had a replication failure. Please see attached txt files for more information. `n $(Get-Content -Path .\causeOfFailure.txt)" -attachment error.zip
```

Comment: THis definitely seems to be on the right track but the output in the email said this.

```&System.Management.Automation.EngineIntrinsics.InvokeCommand.ExpandString(Source Controller: AKOAWS-DC3```

 What is the &System.Management.Automation part mean and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: @ATH1RSTYM00SE see my updated response. I thought your command was in the text file and you wanted to execute that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of the way you are constructing the body string.

You already have the content of the `causeOfFailure.txt` in a variable `$fileContent`, so there is no need to do a Get-Content on the same file again.

I would suggest you create your body in a separate variable first, to make the code more readable.
There are several options for this, like

Make use of a [Here-String](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-use-here-strings-with-powershell/)

```
$body = @"
The following Domain Controller has had a replication failure. Please see attached txt files for more information.

$fileContent
"@
```

Or insert a NewLine followed by the `$fileContent` using the `-f` [Format operator](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html)

```
$body = 'The following Domain Controller has had a replication failure. Please see attached txt files for more information.{0}{1}' -f
        [Environment]::NewLine, $fileContent
```

Or simply create as one double-quoted string

```
$body = "The following Domain Controller has had a replication failure. Please see attached txt files for more information.`r`n$fileContent"
```

Whichever you find is the most readable/maintainable method for your code.

Then for the part where you use the `Send-MailMessage` cmdlet.

Here again, writing out all parameters as one long line can make the code less readable and by doing that, mistakes are easily made.
There is a better way to use a cmdlet with lots of parameters, known as [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting).
Applied to your code, this looks like:

```
# create a hashtable object with all parameters you want to use for Send-MailMessage
$mailParams = @{
    SMTPServer  = 'localhost'
    To          = 'myemail@email.com'
    From        = 'myemail@email.com'
    Subject     = "TESTING Active Domain Replication Failure TESTING"
    Body        = $body
    Attachments = 'error.zip'
}

Send-MailMessage @mailParams
```

Hope this helps